# ''Error: $controller:ctrlreg A controller with this name is not registered

Tags: html, angularjs

I am following a video tutorial on AngularJS on safaribooks 
and on Lesson 3.1 even though I have the same code as in the video I get the error specified in the title.

Here's my code:

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body style="padding: 50px">
<div ng-controller = "AlbumListController">
<p><input placeholder="Type to search..." type ="text" ng-model="searchFor" size="30"/></p>
<p>
There are {{ albums.length}} albums available to view:
</p>
<div class="album panel panel-primary" ng-repeat="album in albums | filter:{ title: searchFor} | orderBy: 'date'">
    <!-- --> 
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div style="float: right"> {{album.date}}</div>
        {{ album.title }}
    </div>
        <div class= "description">
            {{ album.description}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function AlbumListController ($scope) {
    $scope.albums = [ { name: 'madrid1309', title:'Weekend in Madrid', date: '2013-09-01', description: 'FUN FUN FUN FUN'},
{ name: 'iceland1404', title:'Holiday in Iceland', date: '2014-09-01', description: 'FUN FUN FUN'},
{ name: 'thailand210', title:'Sun and fun in Thailand', date: '2012-09-01', description: 'FUN FUN'},
{ name: 'australia', title:'A wedding in Melbourne', date: '2011-09-01', description: 'FUN'}];
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[The code from video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiuTL.jpg) - it's supposed to be identical to mine and we have the same setup since I followed step by step from start and haven't had issues so far.

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xQLZ.jpg)

I noticed there were answers for this question on this website before but they didn't answer my question.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If that's how they create a controller, the tutorial is completely outdated. This would have worked with angular 1.0. But we're at 1.6 now and a whole lot of changes have happened in 5 years. Use the official documentation. Not some outdated youtube tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed your code. I have also left comments inline for you.

First, define the name of the angular app at the top level.

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">
```

Second, add a function that will be executed when the file is parsed in the browser and add your code within that code. So here is what the code looks like.

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body style="padding: 50px">
    <div ng-controller="AlbumListController">
        <p>
            <input placeholder="Type to search..." type="text" ng-model="searchFor" size="30" />
        </p>
        <p>
        There are {{albums.length}} albums available to view:
        </p>
        <div class="album panel panel-primary" ng-repeat="album in albums | filter:{ title: searchFor} | orderBy: 'date'">
        <!-- -->
            <div class="panel-heading">
            <div style="float: right"> {{album.date}}</div>
            {{album.title}}
            </div>
            <div class="description">
            {{album.description}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    /* Note that this function is gonna be called right after
    definition so everything here gets to be executed */
    (function() {
        /* First create the Angular App using the name defined at ng-app */
        var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', [])

        /* Define the controller */
        var AlbumListController = function($scope) {
            $scope.albums = [{
                name: 'madrid1309',
                title: 'Weekend in Madrid',
                date: '2013-09-01',
                description: 'FUN FUN FUN FUN'
            }, {
                name: 'iceland1404',
                title: 'Holiday in Iceland',
                date: '2014-09-01',
                description: 'FUN FUN FUN'
            }, {
                name: 'thailand210',
                title: 'Sun and fun in Thailand',
                date: '2012-09-01',
                description: 'FUN FUN'
            }, {
                name: 'australia',
                title: 'A wedding in Melbourne',
                date: '2011-09-01',
                description: 'FUN'
            }];
        }

        /* A good advice using AngularJs is that don't just rely on the 
        name of the parameter but rather use the $inject element to 
        specify which modules should be injected. Otherwise you when 
        minifying the javascript code the name of the parameters would
        change and your code will break. */ 
        AlbumListController.$inject = ['$scope']

        /* finally register the controller */
        myApp.controller('AlbumListController', AlbumListController)
    })();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, that way of creating controllers is outdated. You can make the following changes to get your code working:

- Change `<html ng-app>` --> `<html ng-app="app">`
- Change the contents of your `<script>` tag to be as follows:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('AlbumListController', function($scope) {
    $scope.albums = [{
        name: 'madrid1309',
        title: 'Weekend in Madrid',
        date: '2013-09-01',
        description: 'FUN FUN FUN FUN'
      },
      {
        name: 'iceland1404',
        title: 'Holiday in Iceland',
        date: '2014-09-01',
        description: 'FUN FUN FUN'
      },
      {
        name: 'thailand210',
        title: 'Sun and fun in Thailand',
        date: '2012-09-01',
        description: 'FUN FUN'
      },
      {
        name: 'australia',
        title: 'A wedding in Melbourne',
        date: '2011-09-01',
        description: 'FUN'
      }
    ];
  })
```

Comment: Yep that was it. Using the code from Fissio's answer or getting the 1.2 angularjs file fixed it.